# Why does nginx always send content encoding as gzip

Tags: nginx

I have set gzip to off

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip off;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

server config

server {
    listen       80 default_server;

```
root         /home/www;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

proxy_buffering off;

location /frontend {
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files /dev/null @directphp;
}
}

location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass x.x.x.x:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
}

location @directphp {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  x.x.x.x:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Check it is not set anywhere else

```
cd /etc/nginx/
 grep -R gzip .

./nginx.conf:    gzip off;


service nginx restart
```

yet content is still getiing sent as gzip?

Response Headers

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:51
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 05 Oct 2016 10:00:00 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Any ideas to turn gzip off completely

Comment: Show server config

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP scripts are probably sending the response gzipped - you should check if you can disable gzip there too. One way to enable gzip in PHP is by using `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`, so you could change that to `ob_start();`